# How can I register objects to a specific datasource in Ebean?

Tags: java, orm, ebean

I am using ebean for java persistence and need configure access to multiple databases so I have something like the following in my ebean.properties.

```
datasource.sqlserver.username=test
...
datasource.ora.password=junk
...
```

I want to associate specific objects to a particular database so that when I generate DDL for example, it generates a different set of tables for each database. Can this be done? With my current configuration it seems that any class annotated with @Entity is picked up and included in whichever server I access - I tested with the following code. I don't have a default set in my ebean.config.

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.setId(4);
f.setSynopsis("Foo 4");     
Ebean.getServer("sqlserver").save(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Ebean description](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaEbean) in the Play documentation

There are samples how to split models to different databases (showed as `ebean.orders` and `ebean.customers`)

You need to use `default` config + some additional one and specify which models goes to which config. There's a [documentation for configuring databases](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaDatabase) (which also uses orders and customers as a sample)